# Pods not found when downloading project zip from GitHub [iOS]

Tags: ios, git, github, cocoapods

I downloaded a zip of my own project from github but keep running into an error on building it. 2 out of 5 libraries I installed using cocoapods, though present in the pods folder, aren't identified by Xcode, specifically, SDWebImage and YTPlayerView.
Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When downloading a git project, the project comes with the `Podspec` file, which specifies which dependencies need to be **downloaded**.  To download the required dependencies for your project, you can run

```
pod install
```

Also, to make sure that the dependencies are loaded, open the `.xcworkspace` file.  If you can't find the workspace, you can go to your project directory and run

```
open `ls | grep xcworkspace`
```

Comment: I did run pod install and the pods install successfully. The problem persists, however.

Comment: Yes, I opened the workspace file. No developments as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

As intboolstring said, ensure you run `pod install` inside the directory of the project you have downloaded, however what I have found is that you should also **build** the project **after** running pod install, as it sometimes does not link the pods to the project. Do this using the `.xcworkspace` file.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing and the pods are installing successfully. However, I keep running into the same problem. I did notice that the local podspec folder was empty. Does this have something to do with the way i pushed the project to github ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with the pods. Adding import *pod name* to the affected classes fixed it.
For some reason, the local copy of the app works fine, even without said import statements.